# VBS Foolproof way to check if site has loaded

Tags: internet-explorer, if-statement, vbscript

I am having some issues with a script that loads a website. Basically, it sucks at detecting when the site is completely loaded, and it then starts doing errors because it cant find the designated objects.

Is there a way, instead of using ie.readystate or ie.busy, to check if site is completely loaded? Maybe by something like a loop that checks if the object is there, before Setting it?

Like:

```
For Each wnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
  If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set IE = wnd
    Exit For
  End If
 Next

IE.navigate2 "xxxx" 
 IE.Visible = 1   

Do Until IE.document.getElementByID("username").Value = "xxxx"

 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("username") 
 Helem.Value = "xxxx"    
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("password")
 Helem.Value = "xxxx"   
 Set Helem = IE.document.forms("signupForm")
 Helem.Submit

Loop
```

ie.busy and ie.readystate (any combinaton) just seems very unstable when loading a form..

I could just use wscript.sleep to ensure the website is completely loaded, but that could be upwards of 10 seconds or more of wait between execution.

Any ideas? :)

Edit:
As Requested:

One thing i have attempted, as someone claimed they had success doing that, is below:

```
Do while ie.readystate <> 4 wscript.sleep 200 Loop
Do while ie.busy wscript.sleep 200 Loop
```

Another is:

```
Do while ie.readystate <> 4 wscript.sleep 200 Loop
Do Until ie.readystate = 4 wscript.sleep 200 Loop
```

And ofcourse been trying them separately as well.

Issue is, once the site is flagged as loaded (readystate = 4) its not really 100% loaded. So when i try to do, for example:

```
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("username") 
Helem.Value = "xxxx"
```

Then i will get an error because it couldnt find the object.

Comment: Let us know the ways you have tried `ie.busy` and `ie.readystate` properties so far (edit your question), and what issues show in all odd case(s)

Comment: As requested. Altho im not sure why its relevant.. Tryed ie.readystate and ie.busy in every form i could think of, will always end up with an error filling the forms i have to fill, because its missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, there are 3 ready states that you need to check.

1. The InternetExplorer object (ie.ReadyState = 4)
2. The document readystate (ie.document.readyState = "complete")

and for it to be  completely foolproof:

3. The readystate of the document frames (if the page has frames, and this might need to be a recursive check)

Here's a VBScript adaptation of a VBA sub that I've used for this task.

```
' web page load timeout in 10ths of a second
Const WAIT_TIMEOUT = 300
Const ERR_TIMEOUT = 1000
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

Sub WaitUntilLoaded(ie)
    Dim i, j, ready

    ' wait for page to connect
    i = 0
    Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        WScript.Sleep 100
        i = i + 1
        If i > WAIT_TIMEOUT Then
            Err.Raise ERR_TIMEOUT, , "Timeout"
        End If
    Loop

    ' wait for document to load
    Do Until ie.document.readyState = "complete"
        WScript.Sleep 100
        i = i + 1
        If i > WAIT_TIMEOUT Then
            Err.Raise ERR_TIMEOUT, , "Timeout"
        End If
    Loop

    ' wait for frames to load
    Do
        ready = True
        For j = 0 To ie.document.frames.Length - 1
            If ie.document.frames(j).document.readyState <> "complete" Then
                ready = False
                WScript.Sleep 100
                i = i + 1
                If i > WAIT_TIMEOUT Then
                    Err.Raise ERR_TIMEOUT, , "Timeout"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Loop Until ready
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly your code, and mine is prolly crappyer at error checking or something.. but using Do while ie.readystate <> 4 or ie.busy or ie.document.readystate <> "complete"
wscript.sleep 500
Loop

Do until ie.document.readystate = "complete"
wscript.sleep 500
Loop is working like a charm.

Comment: I'm surprised it's working because Or doesn't short circuit in VBScript and you should be getting an exception if you try to access ie.document before the page connects - but if it's working, that's great.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I was able to come up with so far is the code below. It relies on capturing the **DocumentComplete** event of Internet Explorer to detect when the page is fully loaded.

**Features:**

- The script will wait for all elements to be loaded, including **frames**
  and **sub-frames**, before reporting that the page has loaded.
- Avoids unnecessary delays waiting to check various properties like
  **Busy** and **ReadyState** using Sleep.
- The LoadPage function has a timeout safety feature to prevent
  infinite looping, which can be adjusted.

Enjoy **:)**

```
Option Explicit

'Sub Main
'--------
 Dim DocumentComplete
 Dim objIE : Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
 objIE.Visible = True

 If LoadPage("https://stackoverflow.com") Then
    MsgBox "LoadPage completed."
 Else
    MsgBox "LoadPage timed out."
 End If

 Function LoadPage(ByVal strURL) 'As Boolean
'-------------------------------------------
 Const TimeOut = 10 'Seconds
 Dim StartTime : StartTime = Now()
 DocumentComplete = False
 objIE.Navigate strURL

 Do While Not DocumentComplete
    WScript.Sleep(1)
    If DateDiff("s", StartTime, Now()) > TimeOut Then
       LoadPage = False
       Exit Function
    End If
 Loop

 LoadPage = True

End Function 'LoadPage

 Sub IE_DocumentComplete(pDisp, URL)
'-----------------------------------
' Fires when a document is completely loaded and initialized.
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768282(v=vs.85)

 If (pDisp Is objIE) Then
    DocumentComplete = True
 End If

End Sub 'IE_DocumentComplete
```